# JPA - unable to update the entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

We are having a JPA project with Hibernate as the provider running in Tomcat server. Problem is when I am trying to update the entity, it is not happening and leading to exceptions. HostConfiguration is the entity that I want to update using a class SystemDaoImpl. HostConfiguration here in turn has InterfaceConfiguration as the child entity. HostConfiguration has 2 InterfaceConfiguration(s) - trusted and untrusted. My aim is to 
(a) update one of the interface configurations i.e. remove the existing interface config and replace with a new one 
(b) remove the the full host config with all interface configs also and then add a new one. I want to know how can I do this ? I have tried various ways/combinations after going through multiple forums over the net. The code below gives me this exception -

> org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be
>   re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations):
>   [com.cisco.cpm.ipep.system.InterfaceConfiguration#InterfaceConfiguration.IfConfigPKey[type=TRUSTED,ipAddress=/7.7.20.18]]

Appreciate any help on this, thanks.

```
//SystemDaoImpl.java

public class SystemDaoImpl {

//code omiited
@Override

public void setHostConfig(HostConfiguration hostConf) {

       HostConfiguration hc = em.find(HostConfiguration.class, hostConf.getHostname());
       if(hc != null) {
       InterfaceConfiguration trusted = hc.getTrustedInterface();
       InterfaceConfiguration untrusted = hc.getUntrustedInterface();

       if(!hostConf.equals(hc) || !trusted.equals(hostConf.getTrustedInterface()) || !untrusted.equals(hostConf.getUntrustedInterface())) {
       log.info("removing the existing hostconf");
       em.remove(hc);   
       InterfaceConfiguration.IfConfigPKey tpkey = new InterfaceConfiguration.IfConfigPKey();                   
       tpkey.setType(Type.TRUSTED);
       tpkey.setIpAddress(trusted.getIpAddress());
       InterfaceConfiguration trusted1 = em.find(InterfaceConfiguration.class, tpkey);
       if(trusted1 != null) {
       em.remove(trusted1);
       }
       InterfaceConfiguration.IfConfigPKey upkey = new InterfaceConfiguration.IfConfigPKey();                   
       tpkey.setType(Type.UNTRUSTED);
       tpkey.setIpAddress(untrusted.getIpAddress());
       InterfaceConfiguration untrusted1 = em.find(InterfaceConfiguration.class, upkey);
       if(untrusted1 != null) {
       em.remove(untrusted1);
       }
       log.info("now adding the new hostconf: " + hostConf);
       em.merge(hostConf);
       } else {
       log.info("hostConf and existing hostConf are equal");
       }
       }

 //some code removed ...
       }
```

**HostConfiguration.java**

```
@Entity

@Table(name = "host_configurations")

@XmlRootElement(name = "host_configuration")

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

public class HostConfiguration implements Cloneable {
public enum HostType {

    PRIMARY, SECONDARY, SERVICE
  }



@Id

@XmlElement

private String hostname;

@XmlElement

private String peerHostname;

@Enumerated

@XmlElement

private HostType type    = HostType.PRIMARY;
 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

 @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)

 @JoinColumns({

        @JoinColumn(name = "trusted_interface_type", referencedColumnName = "type", nullable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "trusted_interface_ip_address", referencedColumnName = "ip_address", nullable = false) })

@XmlElement(name = "trusted_interface")

private InterfaceConfiguration  trustedInterface;

 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

 @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)

 @JoinColumns({

        @JoinColumn(name = "untrusted_interface_type", referencedColumnName = "type", nullable = false),

        @JoinColumn(name = "untrusted_interface_ip_address", referencedColumnName = "ip_address", nullable = false) })

 @XmlElement(name = "untrusted_interface")

 private InterfaceConfiguration    untrustedInterface;

 //code removed

}
```

**InterfaceConfiguration.java**

```
@Entity

@Table(name = "interface_configurations")

@IdClass(InterfaceConfiguration.IfConfigPKey.class)

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

public class InterfaceConfiguration implements Cloneable {
public enum Type {
 TRUSTED, UNTRUSTED
 }

 @Id

@Enumerated

@XmlElement

private Type type;

@Id

@Column(name = "ip_address")

@XmlElement(name = "ip_address")

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = InetAddressXmlAdapter.class)

private InetAddress ipAddress;

@XmlElement

private Subnet netmask;

@Column(name = "vlan_native")

@XmlElement(name = "vlan_native")

private boolean vlanNative;

@XmlElement

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = InetAddressXmlAdapter.class)

private InetAddress gateway;

@Column(name = "vlan_id")

@XmlElement(name = "vlan_id")

private int vlanId;

//code removed

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem ist that the code has a/Cascade on the children's declarations and b/ tries to manipulate the children directly without updating the parents references.  With the Cascade option the use case for delete of the HostConfiguration including the two InterfaceConfiguration goes like:

```
em.remove(hc);
```

and for modifying the InterfaceConfigurations on the HostConfiguration like:

```
hc.setTrustedInterface(...);
hc.setUntrustedInterface(...);
entityManager.merge(hc);
```

If you like to manage the children and parent entities explicitly remove the Cascade annotations.

Comment: With cascade, I am trying to modify the children using the approach you mentioned above i.e.

hc.setTrustedInterface(...);
hc.setUntrustedInterface(...);
entityManager.merge(hc);

However, this is not helping me.

Comment: Can you update your source code? In that case it shall not contain em.remove(trusted1); anymore, right? What error do you now receive?